# How do I use my final blast, or my revive?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I've already bought a final blast and a revive thing, but it doesn't seem to appear anymore? How do I make it appear again?

Comment: I have purchased a pack of them, and I can't see the pack anymore?

Answer (score 3):

Both of those are single use items, so if you have already used them, you will need to buy them to use them again.

Comment: I purchased a pack, and it says that I still have them?

Comment: They should appear at the appropriate points, if they don't, you've likely used them, or something is bugged somewhere.

Comment: Must be a bug, I'm not seeing them. They still have the green thing next to them indicating that I have them. Thanks :)

Comment: The correct time for them to appear should be at the end of a round right after you die. They should each appear as a big square button at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

To use them, you must die first and then use them.

Answer (score -1):

When you die, click the Heart button and it'll use your Revive. The final blast should be next to it too.